# How to manage BigQuery tables post firestore backfill [google-bigquery]

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am interested in learning how to manage BigQuery post firestore backfills.

First off, I utilize the `firebase/firestore-bigquery-export@0.1.22` function with a table named **'n'**.  After creating this table, 2 tables are generated `n_raw_changelog`, `n_raw_latest`.

Can I delete either of the tables, and why are the names generated automatically?

Then I ran a backfill, because the previous collection preceded the BigQuery table using:

```sh
npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection \
--non-interactive \
--project blah \
--source-collection-path users \
--dataset n_raw_latest \
--table-name-prefix pre \
--batch-size 300 \
-query-collection-group true
```

And now the script adds 2 more tables with added extensions
i.e. `n_raw_latest_raw_latest`, `n_raw_latest_raw_changelog`.

Am I supposed to send these records to the previous tables, and delete them post-backfill?
Is there a pointer, did I use incorrect naming conventions?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888233/13171940)?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-configure-the-export-collections-to-bigquery-extension-and-use-sql-full-power-on-your-f3565d809b96), those two tables are part of the dataset generated by the extension.

For example, suppose we have a collection in Firebase called orders, like this:
[image: Firebase collection]

When we install the extension, in the configuration panel shows as follows:

[image: Configuring the extension]

Then,

> As soon as we create the first document in the collection, the extension creates the `firebase_orders` [dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets-intro) in BigQuery with two resources:
>
> [image: BigQuery dataset]
>
> - A [table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables-intro) of raw data that stores a full change history of the documents within the collection... Note that the table is named `orders_raw_changelog` using the prefix we configured before.
> - A [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro), named `orders_raw_latest`, which represents the current state of the data within the collection.

So, these are generated by the extension.

From the command you posten in your question, I see that you used the `fs-bq-import-collection` script with the `--non-interactive` flag, and pass the `--dataset` parameter with the
`n_raw_latest` value.

The `--dataset` parameter corresponds with the **Dataset ID** parameter that is shown in the configuration panel above. Therefore, you are creating a new dataset named `n_raw_latest` which will contain the `n_raw_latest_raw_changelog` table and the `n_raw_latest_raw_latest` view. In fact, you are creating a new dataset with your current registries, and not updating the dataset you created for instance.

To avoid this, as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md#run-the-script), you must use the same **Dataset ID** that you set when configuring the extension:

> - `${DATASET_ID}`: the ID that you specified for your dataset during extension installation

See also:

- [Automated Firestore Replication to BigQuery](https://medium.com/@ammppp/automated-firestore-replication-to-bigquery-15915d518e38)
- [Stream Collections to BigQuery - GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export)
- [Import existing documents - GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md)